# Roles Based Authorization in Angular

Tags: angular, typescript, authorization, roles, role-base-authorization

I receive a role of a user from database after login. I have given a array of roles in the sidemenu components where different roles are given. Then I tried to check if the role I received from database is included in the roles array or not. If the role is included in the array of roles, then I tried to move that menu to a reconstructed sidemenu. I put the function in ngOnIt() so that it can be loaded immediate after the login But the function is not loading due to its asynchronus behavior. How can I solve this without using async await in angular?

```
 menuItems = [
    {
      label: 'File Info',
      subMenuItems: [
        {
          label: 'New File',
          link: 'fileinfo/newfile',
          roles: ['General'],
        },
        {
          label: 'Search File',
          link: 'fileinfo/searchinfo',
          roles: ['User', 'General', 'Admin'],
        }
      ],
      isOpen: false
    },
    {
      label: 'File Info Settings',
      subMenuItems: [
        {
          label: 'Supplier Information',
          link: 'supplierlist',
          roles: ['User', 'General'],
        },
        {
          label: 'File Owner',
          link: 'fileownerlist',
          roles: ['User', 'General'],
        },
        {
          label: 'Purpose',
          link: 'purpose',
          roles: ['User', 'General'],
        },
        {
          label: 'Filetype',
          link: 'filetype',
          roles: ['Admin'],
        },
        {
          label: 'Against',
          link: 'againstlist',
          roles: ['User', 'Admin'],
        },


      ],
      isOpen: false
    },

  ];

This is the original Side menu.
```

I tried to reconstruct the above given menuItems if the role of the user is included on the roles array.
The function to reconstruct the side menu is given below:

```
this.service.getUserRoleFromLocalstorage().subscribe(role => {
      this.userRole = role;

      const newMenuItems: any = []; 

      this.menuItems.forEach((item) => {
        const allowedSubMenuItems = item.subMenuItems.filter(i => i.roles.includes(this.userRole));
        console.log(allowedSubMenuItems);

  
        if (allowedSubMenuItems.length > 0) {
          const newItem = { ...item, subMenuItems: allowedSubMenuItems };
          newMenuItems.push(newItem);
        }
      });

      this.menuItems = newMenuItems;
    });
```

The function is used in ngOnInit() so that it works immediately after the login. But the function is not loading first time due to asynchronus behavior. When I reload the page then it works fine.

Comment: Use `signal` if you are using the latest version of angular `Observable` otherwise.